# Java Collections: List<Animal> tiger = new ArrayList<Tiger>() WRONG

Tags: java, generics, collections

Tiger class is extends from Animal Class.

When I declare: `List<Animal> tiger = new ArrayList<Tiger>();`. I will error at compile-time.

But, I think this line is true for polymorphism. Who can explain for me, please.

Comment: If you/your API design are sure that the "tiger" `ArrayList` will just contain `Tiger`s, why don't you declare it as `List<Tiger> tiger =...` Plus, Animal and Tiger is not an example of polymorphism.. it is inheritance.

Comment: This is the most frequently asked Java generics question of all time.

Answer (score 5):

you cannot do

```
List<Animal> tiger = new ArrayList<Tiger>();
```

that in java. Generic type on left have to be exacly equal (or may not have to be equal, if wild cards are in game - `? extends T` or `? super T`) to generic type on right.

If it was possible then it would be impossible to add new `Lion` to list declared as list of `Animal`s - that would make no sense.

What you can do is:

```
List<Animal> tigers = new ArrayList<Animal>();
tigers.add(new Tiger());
```

(all family of `Animal`s, including `Tiger`s)

or:

```
List<? extends Animal> tigers = new ArrayList<Tiger>();
tigers.add(new Tiger()); // Adding is immpossible now - list can be read only now!
```

(only subclasses of `Animal`) **- list can be read only now!**

Answer (score 4):

A `List<Animal>` would allow you to add a cute little puppy. Which the tigers in the `ArrayList<Tiger>` would then eat.

Polymorphically speaking, you would have

```
List<Tiger> tigers = new ArrayList<Tiger>();
```

Which would allow you to replace use any implementation of `List<Tiger>` if you so desired, relying upon and using the functionality as defined by the interface. What you are trying to do isn't polymorhpism, it is simply an unsafe conversion (particularly for the aforementioned puppy) and is not going to work for reasons illustrated above.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons for this are based on how Java implements generics. The best way I have found to explain it is by using arrays first.

**An Arrays Example**

With arrays you can do this:

```
Integer[] myInts = {1,2,3,4};
Number[] myNumber = myInts;
```

But, what would happen if you try to do this?

```
Number[0] = 3.14; //attempt of heap pollution
```

This last line would compile just fine, but if you run this code, you could get an `ArrayStoreException`.

This means that you can fool the compiler, but you cannot fool the runtime type system. And this is so because arrays are what we call *reifiable types*. This means that at runtime Java knows that this array was actually instantiated as an array of integers which simply happens to be accessed through a reference of type `Number[]`.

So, as you can see, one thing is the real type of the object, an another thing is the type of the reference that you use to access it, right?

**The Problem with Java Generics**

Now, the problem with Java generic types is that the type information is discarded by the compiler and it is not available at run time. This process is called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6). There are good reason for implementing generics like this in Java, but that's a long story, and it has to do with binary compatibility with pre-existing code.

But the important point here is that since, at runtime there is no type information, there is no way to ensure that we are no committing heap pollution.

For instance,

```
List<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myInts.add(1);
myInts.add(2);

List<Number> myNums = myInts;
myNums.add(3.14); //heap polution
```

If the Java compiler does not stop you from doing this at compile time, the runtime type system cannot stop you either, because there is no way, at runtime, to determine that this list was supposed to be a list of integers only. The Java runtime would let you put whatever you want into this list, when it should only contain integers, because when it was created, it was declared as a list of integers.

As such, the designers of Java made sure that you cannot fool the compiler. If you cannot fool the compiler (as we can do with arrays) you cannot fool the runtime type system either.

As such, we say that generic types are *non-reifiable*.

Evidently, this would hamper pollymorphism as well pointed out. The solution is to learn to use two powerful features of Java generics known as covariance and contravariance.

**Covariance**

With covariance you can read items from a structure, but you cannot write anything into it. All these are valid declarations.

```
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Float>()
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Double>()
```

And you can read from `myNums`:

```
Number n = myNums.get(0);
```

Because you can be sure that whatever the actual list contains, it can be upcasted to a Number (after all anything that extends Number is a Number, right?)

However, you are not allowed to put anything into a covariant structure.

```
myNumst.add(45L);
```

This would not be allowed, because Java cannot guarantee what is the actual type of the real object. It can be anything that extends Number, but the compiler cannot be sure. So you can read, but not write.

**Contravariance**

With contravariance you can do the opposite. You can put things into a generic structure, but you cannot read out from it.

```
List<Object> myObjs = new List<Object();
myObjs.add("Luke");
myObjs.add("Obi-wan");

List<? super Number> myNums = myObjs;
myNums.add(10);
myNums.add(3.14);
```

In this case, the actual nature of the object is a List of Objects, and through contravariance, you can put Numbers into it, basically because numbers have Object as the common ancestor. As such, all Numbers are objects, and therefore this is valid.

However, you cannot safely read anything from this contravariant structure assuming that you will get a number.

```
Number myNum = myNums.get(0); //compiler-error
```

As you can see, if the compiler allowed you to write this line, you would get a ClassCastException at runtime.

**Get/Put Principle**

As such, use covariance when you only intend to take generic values out of a structure, use contravariance when you only intend to put generic values into a structure and use the exact generic type when you intend to do both.

The best example I have is the following that copies any kind of numbers from one list into another list.

```
public static void copy(List<? extends Number> source, List<? super Number> destiny) {
    for(Number number : source) {
        destiny.add(number);
    }
}
```

Thanks to the powers of covariance and contravariance this works for a case like this:

```
List<Integer> myInts = asList(1,2,3,4);
List<Integer> myDoubles = asList(3.14, 6.28);
List<Object> myObjs = new ArrayList<Object>();

copy(myInts, myObjs);
copy(myDoubles, myObjs);
```

Comment: Great post :) Thanks :) many useful information that I don't know before :D

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's confusing.  Here's what could go wrong if that type of statement were allowed:

```
List<Tiger> tigers = new ArrayList<Tiger>();  // This is allowed.
List<Animal> animals = tigers;  // This isn't allowed.
tigers.add(new Lion());  // This puts a Lion in tigers!
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh. Yes, you true. your code is right in Polymorphism thinking. But, look at my code that I use for a long time when I just a novie.
And you will see why you should thank to `Collection`:

```
class Animal{   
}
class Tiger extends Animal{

}
public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        List<Animal> animal = new ArrayList<Animal>();  //obvious
        List<Tiger> tiger = new ArrayList<Tiger>();     //obvious

        List<Animal> tigerList = new ArrayList<Tiger>();  //error at COMPILE-TIME
        Animal[] tigerArray = new Tiger[2];     //like above but no error but....

        Animal tmpAnimal = new Animal();
        /*
         * will meet RUN-TIME error at below line when use Array
         * but Collections can prevent this before at COMPILE-TIME
         */
        tigerArray[0] = tmpAnimal;   //Oh NOOOO. RUN-TIME EXCEPTION

        /*
         * Below examples WRONG for both Collection and Array
         * Because here is Polymorphism problem. I just want to make more clearer
         */
        List<Tiger> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        Tiger[] animalArray = new Animal[2];        
    }

}
```

As you see my above code, `Collections` is so "intelligent" when prevent you use `List<Animal> tigerList = new ArrayList<Tiger>();`

You should imagine if someone use: `tigerList.add(a Lion, a Cat,......);` --->ERROR.

So, to Sumarize, here is the different:

> ARRAY: check at RUN-TIME. You will feel more comfortable but DANGEROUS
>
> COLLECTIONS: check at COMPILE-TIME. You will feel angry because it
>   notice error. But, you will prevent errors when Running. !!!!

Maybe below post is over of your question. But I suggest you use WildCard like:

`List<? extends Animal> tigerList = new ArrayList<Tiger>();`

Yes. You might see the idea behind this line. But, the MOST INTERESTING THING is: it will prevent you  change the List. in this case, `add` method.
For example:

`tigerList.add(TIGER); ERROR`

yes. It will prevent you add a tiger, too :)